# Feature from workbench maybe?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table in workbench, and I don't know why theses names can be set up. It ask me to change it. Maybe it concern features that I would like to disable.

```
create table net_shows(
title VARCHAR(100)
,rating VARCHAR(100)
,ratingLevel VARCHAR(100)
,ratingDescription INT(10)
,release year INT(4)
,user rating score FLOAT(4)
,user rating size FLOAT(4)
);
```

release , user appear in blue like a special command.

Comment: A column name is an identifier, and those can't include <space> unless it's a delimited identifier. Also reserved words need to be delimited. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.) In MySQL you use back-ticks to delimit an identifier.

Comment: You can post it as answer of course, thank you.

Comment: Use `user_rating_score` and `user_rating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column name is an *identifier*, and those can't include  unless it's a *delimited identifier* (sometimes called quoted identifier.) Also reserved words need to be delimited. (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.) In MySQL you use back-ticks to delimit an identifier.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Or configure MySQL to be compliant with the SQL standard and use standard double quotes to quote reserved keywords